# Graphical verification of Weibull distribution

Tags: r, data-visualization, survival, weibull-distribution

I want to verify whether Weibull is a good candidate for my distribution in survival analysis.

So I plot log(t) vs log(-log(Kaplan-Meier). But instead of two lines, I get plot where the lines are **somehow connected**.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

```
fit<-survfit(Surv(Time, Status)~Drug, data=pbc)

#weibull
plot(log(fit$time),log(-log(fit$surv)),type="s",xlab="log(time)",ylab="log(-log(survival))")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem doesn't relate to statistics. `plot(fit)` works because `plot()` has the method to draw `survfit class`. But your arguments aren't specific class and don't have any information about *Drug*. So, `plot()` connects all points by one line. You need to treat time, surv, and *Drug* information.

Here is my example:

```
library(survival)
fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ x, data = aml) # using aml as example data

df <- data.frame(time = fit$time, 
                 surv = fit$surv,   # strata has each number of elements.
                 drug = c(rep("a", fit$strata[1]), rep("b", fit$strata[2])))

# plot() draws not data but axes and labs.
plot(log(-log(surv)) ~ log(time), df, type="n", xlab="log(time)", ylab="log(-log(survival))")
lines(log(-log(surv)) ~ log(time), subset(df, drug=="a"), type="s")
lines(log(-log(surv)) ~ log(time), subset(df, drug=="b"), type="s")
points(log(-log(surv)) ~ log(time), df, col=c("red", "blue")[drug]) # to assist you
```

[image]